# ArgumentNullException in DataContext()

Tags: c#, datacontext

I have a Windows Form app that kicks off a .exe child process with specific parameters. When I run the .exe from the commandline, it works fine. But as a child process (with the same parameters), it crashes during an initialization of a DataContext object and throws up an ArgumentNullException for the fileOrServerConnection string in the DataContext constructor:

public DataContext(string fileOrServerOrConnection,MappingSource mapping)

… Which is weird because app.config has the connection string already mapped out. The only thing I can think of at this point is that there’s some conflict with the WF app data sources (there are used to fill in parameter options in the window menu).

The code that launches the child process from the windows form (I edited out some identifiable parts:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\...\amd64\tool.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = queryBuilder.ToString();
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\...\amd64";
p.Start();
```

In the project holding the child process, the DataContext object was called like this:

```
TagDataContext tag = new TagDataContext();
```

TagDataContext was added using the the DataContext designer window (drag and drop from the Server Explorer).

Comment: It sounds like it is not finding the app.config for your child process at all. Where is the *child.config* file and what is the current directory when the child exe is launched?

Comment: Which argument is `null`?  Where is that value coming from?

Comment: And can you also post the line of code where you are launching the .exe?

Comment: Both the Windows Form app and child .exe are separate projects in separate directories, but under the same solution. 

The child.config file path is:

d:\...\solutiondir\tooldirectory\app.config

The windows form app config path is:

d:\...\solutiondirectory\winformappdirectory\App.config

Comment: add Debug.Assert(!File.Exists(Path), "cant find .exe") to check if you're searching in properly directory and if the file really exist

Comment: Does tool.exe.config file exists in that directory?

Comment: A combination of everyone's advice helped out. It turns out that the location of the child process wasn't being updated during building the solution. I changed the child process filename path, rebuilt everything, and now the updated .exe is the one being targeted.

Comment: @llentra answer your own question with the combined suggestions if it worked out.